# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Trying to populate dropdown in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've got the following GridView (I've deleted (snipped) fields which are unnecessary for this process):

```
<asp:GridView ID="DataGrid_ResourceAllocation" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"
    AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="DataGrid_ResourceAllocation_Sorting" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter ="true" CellPadding="1" 
    CssClass="hoverTable"
    HeaderStyle-BackColor="#4DA6A6" HeaderStyle-BorderColor="#4DA6A6" 
    HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Small" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
    FooterStyle-BackColor="#4DA6A6" FooterStyle-BorderColor="#4DA6A6" FooterStyle-ForeColor="White"
    DataKeyNames="Project_ID"
    OnDataBound="DataGrid_ResourceAllocation_OnDataBound"
    OnRowDataBound="DataGrid_ResourceAllocation_RowDataBound"
    OnRowCancelingEdit="DataGrid_ResourceAllocation_CancelCommand"   
    OnRowEditing="DataGrid_ResourceAllocation_EditCommand" 
    OnRowDeleting="DataGrid_ResourceAllocation_DeleteCommand"
    OnRowUpdating="DataGrid_ResourceAllocation_UpdateCommand">  
    <rowstyle backcolor="#b6bfe4" forecolor="DarkBlue" font-italic="false"/>
    <alternatingrowstyle backcolor="#afb7e9" forecolor="DarkBlue" font-italic="false"/>
        <Columns>  

    /****   Snipped code   ****/
    
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Project Owner" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">  
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>  
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Project_Owner" runat="server" Width="70px" Text='<%#Eval("Project_Owner") %>'></asp:Label>  
            </ItemTemplate>  
            <EditItemTemplate>  
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Project_Owner" runat="server" Width="70px" Text='<%#Eval("Project_Owner") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>  
            </EditItemTemplate>  
            <FooterTemplate>  
                <asp:DropDownList ID="nddl_Project_Owner" runat="server" Width="70px" >
                </asp:DropDownList>  
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>        
        
    /****   Snipped code   ****/            

        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="90px">  
        <ItemTemplate>  
                <asp:Button ID="btn_Edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />  
        </ItemTemplate>  
        <EditItemTemplate>  
                <asp:Button ID="btn_Update" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update"/>  
                <asp:Button ID="btn_Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel"/>  
        </EditItemTemplate>  
        <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btn_Add" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="DataGrid_ResourceAllocation_RowCreated" />
        </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>  
        <asp:TemplateField>  
        <ItemTemplate>  
                <asp:Button ID="btn_Delete" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure?');" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" />  
        </ItemTemplate>  
        </asp:TemplateField>        
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Project ID">  
        <ItemTemplate>  
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Project_ID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Project_ID") %>'></asp:Label>  
        </ItemTemplate>  
        </asp:TemplateField>        

        </Columns>  
</asp:GridView>
```

When I edit a record, the dropdownlist should get populated with available data.  So, my OnRowEditing event looks like this:

```
protected void DataGrid_ResourceAllocation_EditCommand(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid_ResourceAllocation.EditRowStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightYellow;
    DataGrid_ResourceAllocation.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    //LoadResourceAllocationGrid();
    DataGrid_ResourceAllocation.DataBind();


    SqlConnection conn = GetConnection();

    GridViewRow row = DataGrid_ResourceAllocation.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
    DropDownList ddList = row.FindControl("ddl_Project_Owner") as DropDownList;


    //DropDownList ddList = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddl_Project_Owner");
    if (ddList != null)
    {
        //bind dropdown-list
        string sqlStr = "Select distinct Project_Owner from tblProjectHealth order by Project_Owner"; // here is another table
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStr, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ad.Fill(ds);

        ddList.DataSource = ds;
        ddList.DataTextField = "Project_Owner";
        ddList.DataValueField = "Project_Owner";
        ddList.DataBind();

        //DataRowView dr = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
        //ddList.SelectedItem.Text = dr["category_name"].ToString();
        //ddList.SelectedValue = dr["ddl_Project_Owner"].ToString();
    }

}
```

The problem is, it fails on the line:

```
GridViewRow row = DataGrid_ResourceAllocation.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
```

The error page comes up with:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
> the collection. Parameter name: index
>
> Description: An unhandled
> exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
> Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
> where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out
> of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the
> collection. Parameter name: index
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 195:            SqlConnection conn = GetConnection(); Line 196:
> Line 197:            GridViewRow row =
> DataGrid_ResourceAllocation.Rows[e.NewEditIndex]; Line 198:
> DropDownList ddList = row.FindControl("ddl_Project_Owner") as
> DropDownList; Line 199:
>
> Source File:
> C:\Users\C35392\Documents\Work\Ad-Hoc\Bob\ResourceAllocation\ResourceAllocation\ResourceAllocation.aspx.cs
> Line: 197
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be
> non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name:
> index]    System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index) +12547654
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
> +15    RAT.ResourceAllocation.DataGrid_ResourceAllocation_EditCommand(Object
> sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e) in
> C:\Users\C35392\Documents\Work\Ad-Hoc\Bob\ResourceAllocation\ResourceAllocation\ResourceAllocation.aspx.cs:197
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnRowEditing(GridViewEditEventArgs
> e) +122    System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEdit(Int32
> rowIndex) +43
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean
> causesValidation, String validationGroup) +715
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source,
> EventArgs e) +89    System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object
> source, EventArgs args) +37
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source,
> EventArgs e) +90    System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object
> source, EventArgs args) +37
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +114
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
> eventArgument) +260
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
> eventArgument) +12
> System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
> sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
> System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
> +35    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> +1639

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `e.NewEditIndex` when this occurs? What is the count of `DataGrid_ResourceAllocation.Rows`?

Comment: I inserted this: int RAC = DataGrid_ResourceAllocation.Rows.Count; and it returned 0.  e.NewEditIndex is the row number I clicked the Edit button on, assuming it's zero-based.  For instance, I clicked the Edit button on the 3rd row and e.NewEditIndex returned 2.

Comment: Isn't that your problem then?  If `DataGrid_ResourceAllocation.Rows.Count` is 0 and `e.NewEditIndex` is 2, then what do you expect to happen when you try to access `DataGrid_ResourceAllocation.Rows[e.NewEditIndex]`?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway - But WHY would it be 0?  There are records in the gridview before I click the Edit button.

Comment: I can't see where you show how the grid is populated with data. I'd guess that you're populating on the client side and not server side so the following code thinks there are no rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Project_Owner" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Project_Owner") %>'></asp:DropDownList>
```

By settings the `Text` property, the site wants to set the SelectedValue to `Project_Owner`. So if the DDL is empty or the value does not exist you get that error.

Better set the SelectedValue in code behind and remove `Text='<%#Eval("Project_Owner") %>'`

Comment: Assuming I'm an idiot (which I'd say is a very fair assumption), how and where would I do this?

Comment: You are binding data to that DDL in the `DataGrid_ResourceAllocation_EditCommand` method. Right after `1ddList.DataBind();` woiuld be a good place.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, as I originally took that code from a textbox.  However, it didn't solve the problem.